# Why does this memoisation function not run in linear time?

Tags: python, runtime, big-o, time-complexity, memoization

I tried to implement memoisation using arrays in a recursive fibonacci function, `fibmem()` expecting the runninng time to come out as O(n). Initially, it looked as though I had it, as it took much faster than the regular recursive fibonacci function to run. (red being the regular `fib()` and green being the `fibmem()`)

[image]

but upon further inspection, (`fibmem()` is represented by red)

[image]

it looks as though `fibmem()` runs in O(someconstant^n) time instead. Here's the code:

```
memo = [0] * 100 #initialise the array
argument = sys.argv[1]

def fibmem(n):

        if n < 0:
            return "NO" 
        if n == 0 or n == 1:
            memo[n] = 1
            return memo[n]
        if n not in memo:
            memo[n] = fibmem(n-1) + fibmem(n-2)
        return memo[n]
```

Now I can get `fibmem()` to run in O(n) time using dictionaries instead of arrays in this way:

```
memo = {0:1, 1:1}

argument = sys.argv[1]

def fibmem(n):

        if n not in memo:
            memo[n] = fibmem(n-1) + fibmem(n-2)
        return memo[n]
```

But I would think that my implementation using arrays is similar. I just can't see why the array implementation of `fibmem()` runs in exponential time. What's going on? How would I go about fixing things?

Comment: The `in` operator is linear for lists. Put them in a set additionally.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @L3viathan I don't quite understand. What do you mean by putting them in a set additionally?

Comment: @imgoingmad You could add it to a set in addition to adding it to a set, and check for membership only in the set. But there are easier ways, like storing it in a dictionary, or checking the length of the list etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **real** problem isn't that the `in` operator scans the list and takes linear time but that you're doing it completely **wrong**.

Your `memo` will be filled with `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ...]`. So when `n` is for example 40, and you're thus checking `40 not in memo`, it will simply **always fail**, because 40 is not a Fibonacci number. Clearly you mean to check whether the 40-th Fibonacci number has already been computed, but that's not at all what you're actually checking. You're instead checking whether 40 is a (already computed) Fibonacci number.

So you get a shortcut only whenever `n` itself happens to be a Fibonacci number, for example at 34. But then until 55, you never get any such shortcuts, **effectively disabling your memoization entirely** (in those ranges). That's why you get exponential behavior there, just like the non-memoized version does earlier on.

Also note that striking interruption of the curve between n=35 and n=36. That's not just a fluke, that's precisely because 34 is a Fibonacci number. The case n=36 goes back to n=35 and n=34, and because n=34 is an instant shortcut, only the n=35 part involves real work. That's why n=36 takes pretty much the exact same time as n=35 (it **was** a fluke that it took slightly **less** when you measured it).

Instead of `if n not in memo:` you should check `if memo[n] == 0:` or `if not memo[n]:`.

Or instead, use a dictionary: `memo = {}`. Then your `if n not in memo:` does what it's supposed to do (because it checks for keys, not for values). That also has the advantage of not being limited.

Comment: You left out any explanation of how to fix it.  Presumably instead of checking `n in memo` he just needs to check `n < len(memo)`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I guess I thought fixing it is the trivial and boring part :-P. But I added that now.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `in` operator, on a list, scans the list from start to finish. It doesn't magically know that you are storing things in order.

You can use sets, which have this built in, to get around this. Or you can use array lookups to check if an array value is set:

```
memo = [1,1] + [0]*98
def fibmem(n):
    answer = memo[n]

    if answer == 0:
        answer = fibmem(n-1) + fibmem(n-2)
        memo[n] = answer

    return answer
```

Comment: Your solution is a pretty bad idea. Better start with the list empty and do `.get(n, 0)` instead.

Comment: Lists don't have .get() methods. But list indexing is faster than hashing. Can you explain why you think the solution is a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks. And thanks L3viathan, for the extra info.

Comment: @AustinHastings You're right, not `get`, but checking the size instead. I think it's a bad idea to  initialize the array with a fixed size, because it will break after 100, and needs all the space even if N is small. Apart from that your solution is good.

Comment: A set is just a collection of unindexed values; you need to use a `dict` to map previously a previously seen input to its computed value.

Comment: @AustinHastings I think you're missing the actual problem, see my answer.